# Macbook Air screen turns yellow/orange when video is in fullscreen.

Tags: macbook-pro

So I noticed recently that when I try to watch YouTube videos or Netflix in full screen on my Macbook Air, the whole screen will wash out with orange and yellow and I can't see anything, but it's perfectly fine if I don't watch it in fullscreen. And on Netflix if I use subtitles, it's normal when someone is talking, but when the text disappears the screen gets an orange tint again. I've tried calibrating the colors through the display section of system preferences but it always tells me that there is an error. I've searched for someone who is having a similar problem but haven't found anyone. Please help! Thank you.

Comment: Do you have something like f.lux installed? And what does console.app say.

Comment: @JohnKeates No, I don't have anything like that installed. And I'm not sure what you're asking for? The calibration screen just tells me there is an error every time I try to adjust white balance.

Comment: Start colorsync utility and run a verify just to check. Also open Console.app and check if it says something about your display or graphics.

Comment: I would run [Apple Hardware Test (AHT)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).  Hold the D key while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter connected.  Run the extended test and see if there is an issue with your video card.

Comment: Same problem on my macbook pro since five days..

Comment: Seems to be f.lux for me, if I disable it it doesn't happen. It seems to be double tinting full screen youtube videos for some reason. I just want one tint, because no tint I can't handle D: Seems to have the same problem with Mac's nightshift as well. It also only happens when the controls hide on the screen, then if I move my mouse around the double tinting goes away... If I scroll the page down a little bit then the problem goes away... hrmmm