# MacBook Air (13-inch, Mid 2012) yellow tint when watching Netflix or YouTube in fullscreen

Tags: macbook-pro, fullscreen, color, youtube, netflix

I noticed recently that when I try to watch YouTube videos or Netflix in full screen on my Macbook Air, the whole screen will wash out with orange and yellow and I can't see anything. But it's perfectly fine if I don't watch it in fullscreen. And on Netflix, if I use subtitles, it's normal when someone is talking, but when the text disappears the screen gets an orange tint again.

I've tried calibrating the colors through the display section of system preferences but it always tells me that there is an error. I've searched for someone who is having a similar problem but haven't found anyone.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/253865/88313

Comment: Same issue here with YT and Netflix. Keeping cursor on tool bar works. Unfortunately I don't have any of the chrome extensions mentioned so they can't be the source of the pb...
I talked to Netfilx support. They tried to help with no success. Google Chrome support wanted to charge me $69!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that this yellow tint problem just occurs on chrome but not on safari. I updated chrome and tested it out - still happening. I then restarted my MBA and it disappeared. Will observe that problem for the next days but I hope that helps anyone. Also, I hardly restart or shut down my MBA, it's been on or in standby for over 2 months.

Update: still happening but found a new solution. I deactivated my extension 'Magic Actions for Youtube' and the problem disappeared. Again I will check if it still occurs.

Answer (score 1):

**Found a solution!**
Just disable Night Shift in the Notification Center.

[image: Step 1]

Step 1: Open `Notification Center` By clicking the very right icon in the menu bar.

[image: Step 2 & 3]

Step 2: Scroll up.

Step 3: Make sure Nightshift is set to `Off`

*This is not ideal, but it seems to have fixed the problem for me. I will update this if the problem reappears.*

Answer (score 0):

Same thing is happening with mine. If I keep my mouse on the play bar at the bottom and keep that up the whole time it doesn't happen, but as soon as I drift my mouse away from the play bar it happens again.

Comment: Updating all my software just solved it for me.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please refrain from adding comments in the Answer section, this is for answers to the questions. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you’ll be able to add [comments](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) and ask follow-up questions. To gain reputation, [answer questions that are clear and concise](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).  Flagging for removal as not an answer. - From Review

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

1. There's a software bug, in which case you should upgrade to the latest software if you're not up to date.
2. If that doesn't seem to solve it, it could possibly be a hardware issue, although it would seem more likely for it to be a software issue.

Solution:

Do an update to the latest software on your computer if you're not up to date. Otherwise, check the status of your hardware and/or take it in to a computer repair shop and get it diagnosed.

-T

Answer (score 0):

A chrome extension called "Picture in Picture" seemed to be affecting fullscreen on youtube and netflix by tinting or yellowing.  Deleted this extension and so far so good.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround for color glitches on fullscreen videos on Mac

Download and install Helium Browser https://apps.apple.com/us/app/helium/id1054607607 which is an always on top web browser (useful anyway for youtube videos).

Put the helium browser window in a corner so that you can barely see it at all.

So when you put a video on fullscreen the color does not shift because the video has never full control over the monitor because Helium window also needs to be displayed!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with macOS Catalina on the Macbook Air 2020 using Chromium based Brave Browser.

Also when disabling all extensions and restarting the browser this issue occurs. When on screen controls are visible (which is the case while moving the mouse for example), the picture is fine. As soon as the controls disappear the color shift appears.

This issue is linked to Chromium, since using Safari everything is fine! Also, this problem only appears if the chrome window is maximized on an external screen which is plugged in via HDMI. It does not appear on the build in screen of the Macbook nor if I connect the external monitor via a DisplayPort to USB-C cable.

#### Solution

Do one of the following:

- Use a non Chromium-based browser for fullscreen videos on external screens (e.g. Firefox or Safari), until the bug is fixed on the Chromium side.
- Connect your external displays not via HDMI (e.g. use a DisplayPort to USB-C cable).

Answer (score 0):

Try toggling hardware acceleration in your browser.

In Google Chrome, go to the Chrome menu > click Preferences > click Advanced in the sidebar to expand more > under System, toggle "Use hardware acceleration when available" > Restart Chrome.

This worked for me in Chrome.  Unfortunately, it didn't work for me in Firefox.  (Firefox also has a [hidden setting](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/performance-settings) that only appears when you uncheck "Use recommended performance settings".)

Your mileage may vary depending on browser version, macOS version, and device since it's related to hardware drivers and the browser version supporting it.