# MacBook Air (13-inch, 2017) [MacOs Catalina 10.15.6] Yellow tint when watching video in Netflix, Youtube or even Videos(Quick Time)

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt

I noticed recently that when i try watching youtube videos in full screen, when i didn't move my mouse and the play bar disappeared , my screen turn yellowish. This happen only during full screen and only if i connect my MacBook Air with an external monitor via thunderbolt (I connect monitor with HDMI through a converter [HDMItoThunderbolt].

If i unplug the monitor from my MacBook, it becomes normal.

Any solution for this? I reach help from apple support but they seems can't fixed this issue.

Comment: Have you had any luck with it? My monitors occasionally become yellow tinted in front of my eyes (Night Shift mode is permanently off).

Comment: So I am having the same problem right now and I am on Big Sur, were you ever able to solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/255255/489896

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps: turn of "Night Shift" when watching movies.

I had this with subtitles. Whenever a subtitle appeared the color became blueish, when it disappeared the color turned to amber.
It took me a while to find out "Night Shift" was the problem. At least turning it off solved mine.

Night Shift can be turned off by clicking in the utmost right corner of the menu bar. On the three horizontal stripes with dashes. This opens the notification center. If you don't see "Night Shift" on the top of the notification center, scroll the center down.
Other method: Open System Preferences > Open Displays > click on "Night Shift" and turn it off.

Hope I was of any help,
regards Peter

Comment: Hi, Peter. 

The problem is i never turn on the night shift ..